# autofs with sshfs not working anymore

Tags: ubuntu, sshfs, autofs, fuse

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10. Before that I backed up my autofs config which worked fine. I appended the line from my old `/etc/auto.master` to the new one:

```
+dir:/etc/auto.master.d
+auto.master
/mnt /etc/auto.sshfs uid=1000,gid=1000,--timeout=30,--ghost,--verbose
```

my `/etc/auto.sshfs` looks like this:

```
mymount -fstype=fuse,rw,nodev,nonempty,noatime,allow_other,max_read=65536 :sshfs\#myuser@mydomain:/mnt/mymount
```

Trying this manually I got `Connetion reset by peer` so I added the option `IdentityFile=/home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa`. Now this happens when I try to access `/mnt` (both with manual and autofs):

```
myuser@laptop /mnt % la
ls: cannot access mymount: No such file or directory
total 4
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    0 Oct 19 10:34 ./
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root 4096 Oct 18 23:17 ../
d?????????  ? ?    ?       ?            ? mymount/
```

The relevant entries from my `/var/log/syslog` are this:

```
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: lookup(program): lookup for mymount failed
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:17:56 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/mymount
Oct 19 00:18:01 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/.hidden
Oct 19 00:18:01 laptop automount[1250]: lookup(program): lookup for .hidden failed
Oct 19 00:18:01 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/.hidden
Oct 19 00:18:03 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/.hidden
Oct 19 00:18:03 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/.hidden
Oct 19 00:18:03 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/.hidden
Oct 19 00:18:03 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/.hidden
Oct 19 00:18:24 laptop automount[1250]: attempting to mount entry /mnt/.hidden
Oct 19 00:18:24 laptop automount[1250]: failed to mount /mnt/.hidden
Oct 19 00:21:57 laptop automount[1250]: umount_autofs_indirect: ask umount returned busy /mnt
Oct 19 00:21:59 laptop automount[1250]: shut down path /mnt
Oct 19 00:21:59 laptop automount[3436]: mounted indirect on /mnt with timeout 30, freq 8 seconds
Oct 19 00:21:59 laptop automount[3436]: ghosting enabled
```

I already checked the UID and GID and they match my user. SSH keys for my user are in place. I also tried to create `/mnt/mymount` manually but strangely it returns "permissions denied" even as root as long as autofs is running (guess it should be this way).

Any ideas what might be wrong? There must by a configuration step I forgot which I did before.

Comment: From your question, I gather it doesn't work manually either.  Better first try to debug *this issue*, e.g. by enabling debug output (see [`sshfs(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sshfs)) -- there're many things involved here (fuse, ssh, autofs)... does a plain `ssh` (or `sftp`) connection work properly?

Comment: Plain ssh works fine. I have to admit I didn't try manual sshfs mount. Sometimes you don't think of the most trivial things. I tried an actually got `Connection reset by peer`. After that I added my ssh key manually to the options. Now I have another error. Will update my question for that.

Comment: @André just for clarification, you're saying that when using both autofs and mounting manually, you get that `cannot access mymount` error with the `?????` thing?

Comment: To be honest after half a year I'm not sure what I tried back then ;-) I guess I tried to mount manually to see if the problem lies in my fuse option or autofs. I could try to reconstruct the problem later on, but today I'm short on time.

Comment: I put my "auto" sshfs as "Programs to run at startup" and I have the command line in that menu. I've tried using `/etc/fstab` but must have abandoned that. +1 to trying manually. Looks like with connection reset by peer, it's a SSH or networking problem.

Comment: Nominating question for closure per comment on answer below that this isn't used any more.

Comment: @Patrick good point. Should I delete it or is it enough to have it closed?

Comment: @AndréStannek closing is fine. I don't think you can delete it since it has answers on it. Closing is just so that stack exchange will stop periodically moving this question back onto the front page.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to run autofs with debugging options?

`sudo automount --debug -f /etc/auto.master` will give you the debug output to the runnning terminal.

Did you add root AND your user to the fuse group?

`sudo gpasswd -a $USER fuse`

Comment: The debug line is very helpful. For me there was an unknown option specified in the `/etc/auto.sshfs` file.

Comment: Found too many responses on how to 'blindly' start applying fixes without knowing the problem. This response shows you how to find the actual error. In my case, I upgrade Debian and I was using a deprecated parameter in the configuration file

Answer (score 1):

There are a few pitfalls that can cause the problems you're running into. As of the time of this answer, you've already solved one of them, but I'll hit them all (your current issue is being caused by #3).

### 1 - The identity file

This is the one you solved. When running `sshfs` from an autofs mount, `sshfs` runs as the root user, so it uses root's ssh key by default. You have to specify `IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa` to use a different key.

### 2 - known hosts

Also because you are running `sshfs` as a user other than the one you normally do, you have to make sure the remote host you're mounting is in the `known_hosts` file. There are a few ways of solving this issue.

1. ssh to the remote host once as root and accept the remote host's key.
2. Add the parameter `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`. This will make ssh accept any key it sees (so introduces a bit of insecurity).
3. Add the parameter `UserKnownHostsFile=/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts`. This will make it use the `known_hosts` file of your normal user.

## 3 - FUSE allow_other

By default a fuse filesystem (which sshfs is) does not allow users, other than the one who mounted the filesystem, to access it. Since autofs runs as root, by default, only root can access it. Anyone else wont have permissions (even root if mounted by a non-root user), even if the actual file permissions say they should be able to. To solve this you have to add the mount option `allow_other`. This will allow users other than the one who mounted it to access the mount. Though access will still obey the file level permissions of files on the mount.

Comment: Doesn't help me. As you saw correctly I already solved the first one. The same counts for the second one as the `allow_other` option is already in the `/etc/auto.sshfs` as you can see in my question. I also use ssh frequently so known hosts entry is there also.

Comment: @AndréStannek wow, old comment, but which `known_hosts` did you check? From your comment about using ssh frequently, I'm guessing you checked your user's `known_hosts`. You need to check root, as it's root who is invoking ssh.

Comment: Sorry, but by now I don't use autofs like that anymore. The Ubuntu installations I used don't even exist anymore ;-)